# Usar variables y listas del editor en la consola de Haskell

Tags: lista, funciones, programación-funcional, haskell, constantes

El programa debería chequear si el número 2 pertenece al conjunto A.
Pero el valor de x (2) y el conjunto A (1, 2, 4, 5) quiero definirlos en el editor y no en la consola.
Tengo este código:

```
x = 2
let A = [1, 2, 4, 5];

chequearSiElem :: Nat -> Bool
chequearSiElem x A 
         |x`elem` A =True
         |otherwise=False
```

Me dice indentación incorrecta y no sé por qué
Solo quiero que devuelva un verdadero o falso, no quiero ni tiene por qué pedir ni un número ni una lista.

Comment: La sentencia `let` va acompañada de `in` para crear un bloque `let..in..`. El compilador espera que las líneas que siguen a `let` vayan indentadas hasta la partícula `in`. A veces se usan los `let..in` dentro de una función para agrupar sentencias, pero no es necesario usar el `let` para declarar `A`, ni tampoco acabar la línea con `;`. Eso es de otros lenguajes.

Comment: ¿Como sería correcta?

Comment: Quita el `let` y déjalo tal cual: `a = [1, 2, 4, 5]` (Usa minúsculas para nombrar valores. Las mayúsculas se reservan para tipos).

Comment: Tira error en la función chequearSiElem, la variable y el conjunto a andan bien.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para añadir el código modificado y el error completo.

Comment: mejor hago otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Como bien menciona el usuario ChelmaCortes, en Haskell los nombres las variables (cualquiera sea su tipo y de dato) y las listas deben definirse en minúsculas ya que las letras mayúsculas se definen para tipos.

Los contenidos de las variables y las listas pueden declararse dentro de un archivo .hs sin problemas (no tira error).

En el ejemplo que puse arriba quedaría:

```
x = 2
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Seguido, la definición de la función

```
chequearSiElem :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
chequearSiElem x (a:xs) 
         |x`elem` (a:xs)=True
         |otherwise=False
```

La función `chequearSiElem` recibe un entero, una lista de enteros y devuelve un valor booleano

Ahora bien, para llamar a la función usando la variable y la lista definida en el editor y que Haskell ejecute la función con los valores respectivos almacenados en estas, se debe escribir el nombre de la función y a continuación las variables que necesite esa función, según cual sea que necesite dicha función.

**Nota:** Las variables, aunque estas sean listas se colocan siempre "sin más trámite", es decir solo las variables sin paréntesis recto y ningún otro sino tipográfico.

En la consola de Haskell se escribe:

```
Prelude> chequearSiElem x a
```

Seguidamente Haskell nos responderá `True` ya que el valor almacenado en la variable `x` (que es 2) se encuentra en la lista `a` (que está conformada por los valores 1, 2, 4, 5)